how to delete a binary tree throught another name
I have the following code:
typedef struct TreeNode
{
    int data;
    TreeNode *lchild, *rchild;
} TreeNode;
TreeNode *CreateBTNode(TreeNode *bt) // pre-build
{
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;
    if (ch == '#')
        bt = nullptr;
    else
    {
        bt = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
        bt->data = ch;
        bt->lchild = CreateBTNode(bt->lchild);
        bt->rchild = CreateBTNode(bt->rchild);
    }
    return bt;
}
void DeleteBiTree(TreeNode *&bt) 
{
    if (!bt)
        return;
    DeleteBiTree(bt->lchild);
    DeleteBiTree(bt->rchild);
    free(bt);
    bt = nullptr;
}
void PreOrder(TreeNode *bt)
{
    if (bt)
    {
        cout << bt->data << " ";
        PreOrder(bt->lchild);
        PreOrder(bt->rchild);
    }
}
int main()
{
    TreeNode *tree = CreateBTNode();
    TreeNode *tmp = tree;

    DeleteBiTree(tree);       // line 1

    DeleteBiTree(tmp);        // line 2

    PreOrder(tree);           // line 3
    
    return 0;
}
    

In this code the tree and tmp have the same address. when i delete this tree using line 1 and output the tree, there is no output and it's right, but when i try to delete the tree using line 2,
there comes to a mess, why? Thanks a lot.

Why TreeNode *&bt and not TreeNode *bt?

DeleteBiTree takes a reference to the pointer argument and modifies it. If you pass different pointers into the function, you'll modify different pointers.

Same situation: void f(int& a) { a = 1; } int main() { int x = 0; int y = x; f(y); cout << x; } prints '0', not '1'.

This is C with cout, not C++. Please don't write code like this and don't learn this. Don't use malloc in C++.

Conceptual issue: tree and tmp initially have the same value, but they are distinct objects with their own addresses. Modifying one object has no effect on the other.

As a side note, a C++ compiler should not compile this code because you call CreateBTNode() without a parameter (which you do not need, anyway).

"there comes to a mess, why?" Because you free the node twice. That's not allowed. Call one free for each malloc, or in C++, call one delete for each new. Or even better, don't use dynamic memory allocation at all. Who's the owner of the node, tree or tmp? Only the owner deletes the node. I.11: Never transfer ownership by a raw pointer (T*) or reference (T&). If you want to share ownership, use a shared pointer.

F.26: Use a unique_ptr to transfer ownership where a pointer is needed and F.27: Use a shared_ptr to share ownership

Why do you delete the tree twice and what is the expected behavior? The solution could be a double pointer, but that's bad practice in C++. I don't remember when I've seen the last double pointer in production code. Another solution could be TreeNode *&tmp = tree;

You have two TreeNode * objects pointing to one TreeNode object. When you call DeleteBiTree(tmp);, you destroy the TreeNode, then set one of those pointers to null. The other pointer now has an invalid value. Once a pointer has an invalid value, the only valid operation on it is assigning it a new value. Even comparing it to nullptr has undefined behaviour.
